# How to pass a singleton reference to ten sibling objects 

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, singleton

If ten classes inherit from a base class, and all ten of the subclasses need access to a singleton, how should the reference to the singleton be passed. I see several ways of going about this, two such being:

1. Call a static method in the superclass that sets the reference of a static object which can then be shared by the subclasses
2. Pass a reference of the singleton to each subclass as an argument in their constructors. Each subclass could store a reference to the singleton object, or pass it into the superclass constructor.

But I don't know what is the preferred way, or if I am missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 provides for less noise and duplication in your code.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I always wonder if there's a more clever way

Answer (score 6):

Why not use the getInstance() method in your singleton class? You don't need to pass it along. Whenever you need it use the static getInstance() method.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating singleton instance in base class like this:

```
static final MySingleton mySingleton = new MySingleton();
```

mySingleton is then automatically available in all the inherited classes.

**EDIT:** As per your comment:

You can get the static reference in base class (if it doesn't require passing runtime argument) like this:

```
static final MySingleton mySingleton;
static {
   SomeClass so = new SomeClass(123, "abc");
   mySingleton = so.getMySingleton();
}
```

Comment: In the program, the singleton needs to exist outside of this particular object family. Thanks though.

Comment: I added another approach, pls see EDIT section which is pretty much same as your option #1 though.